How can I see the array of x, y of batch dataset?
I made a batch dataset with tensorflow with below code.
dataset = dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE, drop_remainder=True)

Dataset shape is below.
<_BatchDataset element_spec=(TensorSpec(shape=(20, 256, 256, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(20, 256, 256, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name=None))>

I wanted to print first array of x with below code but it didn't work, where x and y is input and target data.
dataset[0][0] 


You can use one of these ways to get the first parts of a dataset:
x = tf.random.uniform((100,2))
y = tf.random.uniform((100, 1))
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x, y))  # dataset creation
ds = ds.batch(3, drop_remainder=True)

""" THIS """
for x,y in ds:
  print(x,y)
  break
""" OR THIS """
print(next(iter(ds)))

I think the for-loop does more or less the second solution under the hood. It creates an iterable object with iter, and next gives the next element in the order.
